# No "Example" paragraph style in the Hebrew article layout in Lyx. Why?

Tags: lyx, hebrew, lyx-layouts

I defined my document as "Hebrew article". I have few paragraph styles i.e. "Proof", "Theorem", "Remarks" etc, but there's no "example" paragraph style.

Why? How can I add it?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here's the source of the document:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass heb-article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
theorems-std
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding cp1255
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2cm
\topmargin 2cm
\rightmargin 2cm
\bottommargin 2cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
בדיקה
\end_layout

\begin_layout Problem

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Which module did you use? The *Theorems (AMS)* module for example, has "Example"-layouts.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you elaborate more on how to check/change this?

Comment: Document -> Settings -> Modules.

Comment: but there's a problem:

 \newtheorem{theorem}{\R{����}}[section]
                                            
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Comment: Haven't got a clue, but I know nothing about Hebrew stuff. I suggest you make a minimal example and add that to your question: make a small document (e.g. containing just one theorem) that reproduces the error. Open the `.lyx` file in a text editor, copy everything, and paste it into your question (edit link above the comments). Then select the code, and hit Ctrl + K, or click the `{}` button to highlight as code. Alternatively, View -> Source pane, in LyX, select *Complete source* instead of *current paragraph*, and copy everything there.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I added the source of the document

Comment: Great. I can't answer, but perhaps someone else can. That said, I think you should also rephrase the question now, seeing as it's not about finding an Example-layout, but fixing an error.

Comment: @blueplusgreen if this is a bug, please report it at https://www.lyx.org/trac and put the minimal example there.

Answer (score 3):

I know that it is almost an year later but still. I had the same problem and I was also looking to add this 'Example' paragraph style to the Hebrew article layout. After so many trials I think I finally managed to edit the layout file without any compilation bug reports.

Just add the following rows to the heb-article.layout file and it'll add an 'Example' paragraph style and also 'Exercise' and 'Solution' styles to the layout

```
Style Example
    CopyStyle             Theorem
    LatexName             example
    LabelString           "Example #."
    Preamble
        \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\R{דוגמה}}
    EndPreamble
End

Style Exercise
    CopyStyle             Theorem
    LatexName             exercise
    LabelString           "Exercise #."
    Preamble
        \newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{\R{תרגיל}}
    EndPreamble
End

Style Solution
    Category              Reasoning
    Margin                First_Dynamic
    LatexType             Environment
    LatexName             solution
    NextNoIndent          1
    LabelSep              xx
    ParIndent             MMM
    ParSkip               0.4
    ItemSep               0.2
    TopSep                0.7
    BottomSep             0.7
    ParSep                0.3
    Align                 Block
    AlignPossible         Block, Left
    LabelType             Static
    LabelString           "פתרון:"
    Font
      Shape               Up
      Size                Normal
    EndFont
    LabelFont
      Shape               Up
      Series              Bold
    EndFont
    Preamble
        \newenvironment{solution}%
            {\R{\textbf{פתרון:}}}%
            {\hfill\rule{0mm}{0mm}\par\vspace{0mm}}
    EndPreamble
End
```

My pleasure